# ArangoDB wildcard search is slow

Tags: arangodb

I am working on the below query and trying to implement an ArangoDB wildcard search. The criteria is very simple, I'd like to match records similar to the name or a number field and limit the records to 25. The query works but is very slow, taking upwards of 30seconds. The goal is to optimize this query and get it as close to sub second as possible. I'd like the query to function similar to how a MySQL LIKE would work, matching using the % wildcard on both sides.

https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/release-notes-new-features37.html#wildcard-search

Note, one thing I noticed is that in the release note examples, rather than using FILTER, they are using SEARCH.

Additional info:

- name is alphanumeric
- number is going to by an 8 digit number

```
LET str = CONCAT("%", 'test', '%")
LET search = (
   FOR doc IN name_search
   FILTER ANALYZER(doc.name LIKE str, "text_en") OR
   FILTER ANALYZER(doc.number LIKE str, "text_en")
   LIMIT 25
   RETURN doc
)
RETURN SEARCH
```

Answer (score 2):

FILTER doesn't utilize indices. To speedup your wildcard queries you have to create an ArangoSearch view over a collection and use SEARCH keyword.

Feel free to check the following interactive tutorial (see "LIKE Support" section):
https://www.arangodb.com/learn/search/arangosearch-tutorial-3-7/